# Ordinary differential equation Help!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Math-heads, I'm really struggling with the following ODE which **has to be solved by the method of variation of constants** and perhaps with some initial substitution:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = -2\frac{y}{x}+xy^2$

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This OE is not a linear equation! I know that the method is applicable foe linear ones. Please light my mind if I am missing something.

Comment: Towards making a simplifying substitution, note your equation is a [Bernoulli equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation).

Comment: Thanks for the help! The reference to the Bernoulli equation is a game changer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: As @David commented correctly, this non linear ODE is a Bernoulli one. For solving it, you can always set $w=y^{1-n}, n\neq 1,~ 0$ in the original ODE to find another linear one. Here you have $n=2$, because of the power of $y$, so $w=y^{-1}$ and then we are lead to solve the linear following ODE: $${-w'}+\frac{2}{x}w=x$$

Comment: You always give credit to others, and your sportsmanship is commendable, always! +1

Comment: I knew this OE, but I was confused by the method the OP suggested. In fact, @David Mitra's comment made me sure that my idea was right. Thanks.